# Minimum of some functions

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Denote $U=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n):0<x_j<1 (1\leq j\leq n),\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=1\}$.

Let $f_i=f_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ ($1\leq i\leq n-1$) be $n-1$ real functions which satisfy:

$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i=\prod_{j=1}^nx_j$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i=1-x_n-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_j^2$ for any $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in U$.

How to compute $\min_{1\leq i\le n-1}\min_{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in U}\{f_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\}$? Whether it equals to a strictly positive real number which is independent of $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$? Thank you so much.

Comment: so $\prod_{i=1}^nf_i=1$ is that correct?

Comment: thank you, the right should be product. I have revised the condition